# Rails + フロントエンドの場合のディレクトリ構成

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, next.js

Railsとフロントエンドを一つのリポジトリで開発する場合の一般的なディレクトリ構成がわかりません。

例えばRails API + Next.jsの場合下記の選択肢があるかなと思います。

1. Railsの中に`frontend`という名前Next.jsのディレクトリを作る。
2. Next.jsの中に`api`という名前でRailsのディレクトリを作る。
3. 別のリポジトリにすべき。

どのような構成が一般的でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

Next.js ということで、おそらく、フロントエンドは SSR する別サーバーとして動作するのだと思います。であるならば、サーバーそれぞれ別々に起動することができると思うので、であるならば、

> 3. 別のリポジトリにすべき。

が一般的かな、と思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。なるほどです。別のリポジトリにすると、両方に跨った機能のデプロイが大変かな〜と想像しているのですがその辺はどんな感じでしょうか。

Comment: 一般的なバックエンドサーバーは、機能を追加するときに後方互換を保つようにするのが一般的です。(api のバージョニング)それを行うことで、少なくともバックエンドからデプロイすれば、問題なくリリースできるはず、という感じです。